# Error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined NOOB

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am getting this error when i am trying to build announcement system and i am getting this error every time. This is one of my first PHP things i have done so if it is able can i get help in as simple as possible way

```
<?php
$servername = "1234";
$username = "asd";
$password = "123";
$dbname = "admini";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // prepare sql and bind parameters
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO information (name, info) 
    VALUES (:name, :anouncement)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':info', $info);

 $name = "sam";
 $info = "i hope this works without errors";
$stmt->execute();

    echo "New records created successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
$conn = null;
?>
```

Comment: You have `VALUES (:name, :anouncement)` and bind to `$stmt->bindParam(':info', $info);`

Comment: that fixed it thank you

Answer (score 0):

How I see you define params late meybe you should write like this

```
  //first params define 
     $name = "sam";
     $info = "i hope this works without errors"; 
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO information (name, info) 
VALUES (:name, :anouncement)");
     //then bind 
     $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
     $stmt->bindParam(':anouncement', $info); //also change  info into anouncement
```

Also change  info into anouncement for second param